# Trouble Setting Async Request Result

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, request

I'm having difficulty accessing the result of an asynchronous request to an rss feed. I referred to the post, [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), which suggests using Promises. I implemented a Promise, which resolves, but still cannot access the result of the request outside the request function.

I am attempting to set the variable `film` to the request result, but can only seem to get `undefined`.

```
var request = require("request");
var parseString = require("xml2js").parseString;

var url = 'http://feeds.frogpants.com/filmsack_feed.xml';

var film;

request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                parseString(body, function(err, result) {
                    var feed = result.rss.channel[0].item.reduce(function(acc, item) {
                        acc.push(item);
                        return acc;
                    }, [])
                    resolve(feed)
                })
            }
        }
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        film = data;
    })
})

console.log(film)
```

Logging `feed` from within the request function returns the results that I am looking for. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced, but I think the issue is that console.log is executed before your request (asynchronous) returns a result.
Perhaps you should try returning "film" from the last then() and chain another then() to console.log that var

```
    ...    
    .then(function(data) {
        return film = data;
    })
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
})
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you for the clarification!